# Sample work-flow when using PhpStorm & GitHub on a Remote Server?

Tags: github, phpstorm

This is my current work-flow:

I have a web-server on my development machine (on the same network). It houses my project & I use Notepad++ to make live-edits to the code. I make code edits from my laptop, refresh the page (which I am accessing thru hostname on my laptop) to see my `PHP`/`HTML` edits & when I'm satisfied, I merge to the master branch on GitHub.

In an effort to become more familiar with IDEs for `PHP`, and have some great debugging capabilities, I want to start using PhpStorm.

I thought of moving the web-server & GitHub Desktop to my laptop and just leaving the databases on the development machine, but that creates other issues.

My work-flow might not be modern. Could you help me understand how a new & similar work-flow could potentially be setup with PhpStorm in the mix? How have you seen it done?

I'm using `Laravel` which has a ton of files, so constant full-syncs instead of deltas would be too much time wasted.

Comment: How do you connect to your dev machine to copy your files there? FTP or shared folder? Just use Auto deployment option and once you are saving the file in IDE it will upload it there (so not full sync is required). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/deploying-applications.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/

Comment: I noticed that feature last night, Im using FTP. I was going to check how it functions if something is added to a project from the dev machin end.

Comment: The IDE is built on "local code first" idea .. so it can auto-upload from local to remote (be it modified in IDE only or even outside -- there is an option for that) .. but it will not auto-download remote changes to local.

Comment: Okay, I think that leveraging those two features can keep my work flow pretty close to what I’m used to. Another issue I found is hostname on DB auth, since I’m debugging on my laptop but deploying remotely (databases are on dev machine). I would fix it with “if connecting with localhost as the host fails” logic to avoid having to constantly modify it.  I couldn’t find a feature in the docs for this

Comment: I do not know/understand what you mean here. If you need different connection details *in your code*, consider using ENV variables (e.g. https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv). If it's DB connection in actual IDE -- use 2 different: one for local host and one for remote.

Comment: Thank you, I'm learning lots of new things at once. This is exactly what I needed and Laravel comes with it.